IEnumerable yield return with two lists
Sorry if this is too silly :-)
I have a working code of this type:
public IEnumerable<Class1> DoSmth()
{
   foreach (...)
   {
      output = DoComplexCalc();
      yield return new Class1(output);
   }

   yield break;
} 

Let's say I want to keep "yielding", but I now need to return two lists (like the example below, but I don't know how to utilise "yield" in this case)
public (IEnumerable<Class1>, IEnumerable<Class2>) DoSmth()
{
   var list1 = new List<Class1>();
   var list2 = new List<Class2>();
   foreach (...)
   {
      output = DoComplexCalc();
      if (output.Whatever)
      {
         list1.Add(new Class1(output));
      }
      else
      {
         list2.Add(new Class2(output));
      }
   }

   return (list1, list2);
} 

Of course, I could have two separate functions, etc, but what if I wanted to go only once through the loop below?
   foreach (...)
   {
      output = DoComplexCalc();
      ...
   }

Thanks

Why not go back to the original and let the caller decide what to do with the output at the callsite instead?

Of what type is output?

Ok, it's not actually "new Class(output)". It's more like "new Class1(set of output props)" and "new Class2(a different set of output props)". I understand about letting the caller decide, but what if I wanted to specifically keep the structure like this and hide all that from the caller? The only way to do it is as in the second DoSmth(), correct?

You returned 2 IEnumerables, so anyway you will eventually go through the collection twice.

Do Class1 and Class2 share any common interface or base class? Should they perhaps? How are they used?

Class1 and Class2 are not really related. It's just that the "output" contains enough info to produce both unrelated classes, like a factory of some sort.

If there is a decent chance that the resulting list(s) may not be enumerated completely, then using yield return may have performance benefits. But if you always go through the entire list(s) then you might as well go for the variant that builds both lists completely and then returns them both. This can even have benefits, like being able to easily see that List1 has 5 items and List2 has 43, for example.

You can yield output instead and when iterating creating either class1 or class2 depending on output .Whatever and do what you need with either?

Won't this work?
public IEnumerable<(Class1?, Class2?)> DoSmth()
{
   foreach (...)
   {
      var output = DoComplexCalc();
      
      if (output.Whatever)
      {
         yield return (new Class1(output), null);
      }
      else
      {
         yield return (null, new Class2(output));
      }
   }
}


I suggest adding third property to know if condition was true or false: IEnumerable<(Class1?, Class2?, bool)> DoSmth() ... yield return (new Class1(output), null, true); ... yield return (new Class1(output), null, false)
